# How to hide the home indicator for iPhone X writing a common code in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

In my project i would like to hide the home indicator without writing the same code in every view controller and instead implement it in the appDelegate. I tried

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

I tried like this but its not working commonly. So how can i hide the home indicator without writing in every view controllers and instead implementing from app delegate itself?

Comment: Implement it once in a custom subclass of `UIViewController`, then let all your view controllers inherit from that.

Comment: thanks .. but it would be far easy for me to implement in AppDelegate if possible .. because i am using js file too for view controllers

Comment: Is your root view controller a container view controller (navigation controller or tab bar controller)? If so [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887508-childviewcontrollerforhomeindica) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish this. In my opinion it's not the most elegant and I would agree with Gereon that you'd be better off with creating a subclass of `UIViewController`, implement it there and then have all your view controllers inherit from that base class.

You can however accomplish this using Method Swizzling. See it here: https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/. In your case you can swizzle it in AppDelegate in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and swizzle `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` to your custom function that returns `YES`.

So for swizzling I'd suggest you create a new Category of the UIViewController. And the actual swizzling:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (Swizzling)

+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];
        SEL originalSelector = @selector(prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzledPrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden);
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        const BOOL didAdd = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
        if (didAdd)
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        else
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    });
}

- (BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
{
    return YES; //Doesn't matter what you return here. In this you could return the actual property value.
}

- (BOOL)swizzledPrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden //This is the actual `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden ` call
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: yes i would glad to know swizzling. please help with the code

Comment: Edited the answer. You could do this in AppDelegate if you wanted but I recommend a new file for it. Makes the code cleaner.

Comment: thanks a lot... how to do this in the app delegate ? just include this whole code in app delegate ?

Comment: If you want to - yes. But as I said it really shouldn't be there. Just make a new ObjC file and slap this in it.